# Round robin concurrent algorithm with F# and Task<T>

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, f#

I have a C# API like this:

```
Task<T> Foo(serverUri)
```

Let's say I have 4 possible serverUris. I want to implement a function that will return DiscUnionBar type:

```
type DiscUnionBar of T =
    Safe of T | Weak of T | ConnectionError
```

The implementation will have the following requirements:

1. Do 3 (max) concurrent calls to Foo() with 3 different serverUris.
2. Pick the 2 fastest successful responses. If they give same result T1 and T2 (being T1==T2), stop doing concurrent requests and ignore/cancel requests that are in progress and return Safe of T. If T1!=T2, keep doing more requests (or looking at responses) until two equal responses are found.
3. If any of the requests fails (throws ServerException), try with a serverUri that has not been requested before.
4. If all requests to all 4 servers fail, return ConnectionError.
5. If only 1 request succeeds, return Weak of T.

Is this easy to do given that I cannot use F#'s Async and have to stick with C#'s Task usage? I'm a bit lost on this one.

Comment: Any reason you can't use `async`?

Answer (score 6):

Unless there is a reason you cannot use `Async` *anywhere* in your code, and your only limitation is that `Foo` has to return a `Task`, you should have no problem converting the `Task` resulting from calling `Foo` to an `Async` with [`Async.AwaitTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.awaittask%5B%27t%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D).

This way you can build the logic using F#'s async computation expressions as if `Foo` returned an `Async`

```
let simpleComputation serverUri = async {
    let! fooResult = Foo(serverUri) |> Async.AwaitTask
    (* here you can work with the T returned by Foo's task *)
}
```

I also have good experience with [`FSharp.Control.FusionTasks`](https://github.com/kekyo/FSharp.Control.FusionTasks) library, which lets you use `Task` directly in async computation expressions, without having to call `AwaitTask` explicitly, and helps in Async/Task interop in general. Although some may not like that it tries to hide the Tasks.

Comment: Some do not like that `async` forces the use of `Async.AwaitTask` when calling asynchronous APIs like HttpClient, ADO.NET, EF, AWS SDK, Azure SDK - all non-F# asynchronous APIs in short

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and that is exactly why I mentioned the library :)